# Emacs -- How to gather info and delete window without selecting it

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am looking for some assistance, please, to gather some information about a particular window without necessarily selecting it, and then delete that window if it meets the specified criteria.

The following snippet of a function will only work if the target window is selected, however, I would like the function to operate no matter what window has focus.

```lisp
(defconst lawlist-calendar-buffer "*Calendar*"
  "Name of the buffer used for the lawlist-calendar.")

(if
    (and
      (get-buffer-window lawlist-calendar-buffer (selected-frame))
      (with-current-buffer (get-buffer lawlist-calendar-buffer)
        (eq (window-height) 12)))
  (delete-window (get-buffer-window lawlist-calendar-buffer (selected-frame))))
```

Comment: You can get the list of windows with the function `window-list` is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I generally have 3 windows open when using the calendar buffer and focus might be in any of those three windows.  I would like to see whether the calendar window exists and has a height of 12 -- if it does, then delete that calendar window.  I am trying to avoid using `(select-window (get-buffer-window (buffer-name buffer)))` and then switching back to whichever window previously had focus.  The next step will be to generate a new calendar in a different size window (in a different location / layout) -- but that part I already have handled.

Comment: @lawlist Generally, you can always use `with-selected-window` for temporary window operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code

```
(let ((target-window (get-buffer-window "*Calendar*")))
  (when (and target-window
             (eq (window-height target-window) 12))
    (delete-window target-window)))
```

The function `get-buffer-window` will return nil if the buffer is not visible in current frame. The function `window-height` is passed an existing window, it returns the height of the window. The code above combines these two functions to delete the window the buffer `*Calendar*` is open in, if the the height of the window is equal to 12.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work in either the target window or another window.  To duplicate this scenario, we can essentially just `split-window-vertically` and set the bottom window to a size of 12 and call that buffer `"*Calendar*"` -- the code should work when focus is in either of those two windows.

Comment: This works perfectly for me, are you sure size of Calender is 12? In my emacs the size 9.

Comment: These are the steps I'm using to test your code -- **Step # 1:** `(display-buffer-at-bottom (get-buffer-create "*Calendar*") '((window-height . 12)))` -- **Step # 2:**  Evaluate your code with focus in either window.

Comment: Thanks for the test code. Worked for me perfectly. Can you try this with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: I just tried with a blank empty `.emacs` file, and same result -- the code does not work with the latest Emacs Trunk:  GNU Emacs 24.3.50.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0, NS apple-appkit-1038.36) of 2014-03-19 on MP.local

Comment: Oops there is a typo in the buffer name, "*Calender*" should be "*Calendar*", sorry!